# how to avoid .sql file from a folder

Tags: sql, bash, spool

I am executing

```
#!/bin/bash

PARTITION_LOG=../log/auto_partition.log

PATH=../sql/

cd $PATH
SQL_FILES=`/bin/ls *.sql`
echo "$SQL_FILES"

for File in $SQL_FILES
do
    if [ -f  $File ]

    then

    f=$File

    fi

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -silent username/password@database << _EOF_ > $PARTITION_LOG
    set head on echo off linesize 300 feedback off trim on trimspool on verify off
    spool $PARTITION_LOG
    @$f
    spool off
_EOF_

done
```

`../sql/`   contains 4 files

```
A.sql,B.sql,C.sql,D.sql
```

I don't want to execute `D.sql`.

the above code is executing all $ files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the line

```
SQL_FILES=`/bin/ls *.sql`
```

to

```
SQL_FILES=`/bin/ls [^D]*.sql`
```

should exclude `D.sql`.